# PyQGIS plugin doesn't work layer list combo box

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, python-2.7, pyqt

I want to create a simple QGIS plugin with a simple combo box with list from my layers

in `_ _init_ _` :

```
    legendInterface = self.iface.legendInterface()
    listLayerName = [i.name() for i in legendInterface.layers() if i.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer]
    # add all these layer names to combo box comboLayerList
    self.ui.comboBox_2.addItems(listLayerName)
```

but if I start plugin in QGIS then the combo box not working is empty:

[image]

if I reload my plugin use reload using `Reload plugin` :

[image]

then the combo box is working. If I close QGIS and start again then combo box is not working again. If I again reload plugin then works.

Where is my mistake and my combo box not working?
how to refresh the plugin on start to work combo box?

Comment: I second [@ndawson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/28443/ndawson) suggestion of using a [QgsMapLayerComboBox](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayerComboBox.html). But if you want to stick with your comboboxes, take your code out of the `__init__` method as this only runs when the plugin is loaded. Assuming you used the **Plugin Builder** plugin, you can put your code in the `run()` function which is executed when you run your plugin. You should also include `self.ui.comboBox_2.clear()` before `self.ui.comboBox_2.addItems(listLayerName)` to avoid duplicates.

Comment: @ Joseph yes but I hard to do this now because I start without Plugin Builder plugin I will try again

Answer (score 5):

Don't make your own - PyQGIS has a whole library of standard reusable widgets like this. In this case use QgsMapLayerComboBox. All the hard work is done for you, it's stable and unit tested, and will keep UI consistency with the rest of the QGIS interface.

Comment: I try to follow youe proposal and I have add QgisMapLayerComboBox in my ui using QT designer but I take this error :`Couldn't load plugin 

ImportError: No module named qgsmaplayercombobox 

` finaly I try to import from qgis.gui import QgsMapLayerComboBox but without success I have same error

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using?

Comment: I use QGIS 2.14.20

Comment: How are you creating the `QgsMapLayerComboBox` in Qt Designer? I usually create a new `QComboBox` and then promote it for example to `QgsScaleComboBox`.

Comment: @Blinxen yes i use Qt Designe how to promote ?